# Possible to set Firefox to go to HTTPS site when press Ctrl+Enter in Location Bar?

Tags: firefox, http, https, redirection, tls

In Firefox, if the user types one word and then presses Ctrl+Enter in the Location Bar (aka urlbar), they will automatically be redirected to:

> http://www.example.com

Is there a way, instead for them to be redirected so they are connected via HTTPS?  As in:

> https://www.example.com

Answer (score 1):

You could try this addon:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/https-by-default/

There are more suggestions here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/ark1ri/how_to_change_ctrlenter_behaviour_to_use_https/